# How to convert space or new line in textarea to a comma delimted PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I am trying to get a result like a,b,c,d  for my array
whatever format in the textarea field is added

```
$mydomain = htmlspecialchars($_POST['domainlist']);
$domainlist = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $mydomain);
$domainlist = preg_replace('#\s+#',',',trim($str));
$domainlist = explode(',', $mydomain);


$keyword = $_POST["keyword"]; 
foreach($domainlist as $domain) {
    $file = file_get_contents('http://' . $domain);
    $searchnum = $keyword ; 

    if (stripos($file, $searchnum) !== false) { 
        echo 'record found on '   .$domain. '<br/>';
    } 
    else {
        echo 'record not found ' .$domain.  ' <br/>';
    }
}
```

for example(notice the extra white space)

user adds

```
a,b  , c, d

or

a     b     c     d

or 

a

b

c

d
```

will all result to

```
a,b,c,d
```

that removes extra white space, convert new line to comma, or convert space to comma and remove extra white space

any idea?

Comment: I think it's not completely clear whether you're intending to create an array or a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it appears that you want an array to loop over, you can split on the characters that you want with `preg_split`, and using `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` will eliminate any extras. Then there is no need for `explode`:

```
$domainlist = preg_split('/[ ,\n\r]/', $mydomain, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: one last question, is it possible to detect if http:// is added I would like to replace with nothing as when the user add an http:// I get an error, so wether the user add an http or not it would be the same

Comment: `str_replace` takes arrays so `$domainlist = str_replace('http://', '', $domainlist);`

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `str_replace` to find out space and newlines char. But i will recommend to use `preg_replace` function as mentioned.

```
$mydomain = htmlspecialchars($_POST['domainlist']);
$domainlist = preg_replace(['/[\s]+/','/[\n]+/'], ",", $mydomain);

$domainlist = explode(',', $mydomain);
```

Result : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/af212f55156ee5770a62adc4c5c70ae820e9c2df

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.